# I need help removing a support beam

Tags: bathroom

Hi my question is I have a support beam I want to replace the 8 support posts. And just put 2 at each end of the beam .so that I can open up the space . My question is can I use steel post or do I need to stick to 2×4's. I am using 3 2by4 put together .. which is stronger?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anybody to answer your question. You should be consulting with an engineer, not asking a bunch of hosers on the internet.

Comment: No information on how far apart those posts are, what kind of weight they're supporting, the beam span or the size of the beam you are removing the support from. Who cares about whether three sistered 2x4's will support the ends when the main beam has the chance of folding in the middle. Sounds like a disaster in the making, unless you get somebody in there that can determine the loading and beam strength needed.

Answer (score 2):

Posts are placed under a beam in very specific places for very specific reasons.  You most likely cannot move those posts at all without compromising the integrity of the beam and whatever is sitting on top of it.

If you really wish to open up the space, you must consult with an engineer to determine what could possibly be done.  Most likely, the scope would be way beyond what you wish to tackle.

Answer (score 1):

I must (partially) agree with other posts. Truth is that you haven't provided enough information (distance between beams, dimensions of the beam, construction type of the house, where is this beam located etc.).Another sad truth (but this is sad for this community) is that even if you have provided all this facts I doubt that anyone here would be able to help you because people over here aren't really experts. I would love to help you but although I'm an engineer I'm not structural engineer; but instead I can tell you about my similar experience: when I was remodeling one old apartment (house was built in 1938) I had to make existing opening twice as bigger. Problem was that it was in a supporting wall. Had I did is hired a structural design engineer to take a look at it, he has done his thing and gave me the dimensions of the supporting beam which I should make. I was surprised that those dimensions were almost exactly the same as my contractor suggested they should be without any calculations. When we started this operation, we have inserted several steel support beams (those were temporary supporters) and then we carefully started bringing parts of the wall down. When this was finished we have poured new reinforced concrete beam, and that was it. What I wanted to say: yeah, it can be done it is complex but not by far as complex as people are representing i.e. wanted to be on a safe side so I hired structural engineer but he hadn't told me anything I didn't know already, but I think you should hire contractor to do this job because you don't have skills or equipment for this job.

Comment: The complexity of the two problems in question is quite different - in your case, you were replacing studs with a beam, which is something contractors do all the time.  The OP is attempting to remove supports from a beam - to maintain acceptable levels of deflection and such from the beam likely means installing a much stiffer beam, which is not only a major undertaking, but truly something I wouldn't trust someone other than an engineer or architect to sign off on.

Comment: I disagree; problems are the same from the engineering point of view: in both cases you are increasing the distance between two bearing points. When OP says that he wants to remove supports engineer knows that it really means to put supports on a bigger distance (next to the walls etc. ) .When it comes to your other observation when you have a toothache you don't go to your "street-smart neighbor who knows it all”. Instead you go visit a dentist. Same thing with the house: when I said hire a contractor that presumes engineer; because no one else can't be contractor I hope that's obvious? :)